# Is there a way to get the name of the track Windows Media Player is currently playing?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-media-player

I'd like to query Windows Media player from an external app to find out what track (album and artist) it's currently playing.

Is that information exposed anywhere?

Comment: It should be, as Last.FM's app tracks that info too. (Not the real answer, but halfway there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to write a Windows Media Player plug-in. There's an API for doing this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb262326(VS.85).aspx. And some info on [how to update the plugin wizard to Visual Studio 2008 here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/0edad96a-207d-4c91-8fa7-4226335fd3ae/).

A background User Interface plugin could write the info you want, such as the currently playing track, title, etc., to a file that you monitor. The UI plugin is simply an object that implements IWMPPluginUI.

Answer (score 0):

Well one approach seems to install a "Blogging plugin", which will write the information to the registry, where you would be able to read it.

It's explained here (scroll down to the *Getting Data from Media Player (and iTunes)*
 section:
http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/archive/2005/04/11/407357.aspx

The Blogging plugin is available from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/wm_create.mspx), but you could also write your own plugin to gain more control and choose your desired means of communication.